# React native always 100% width and height depending on parent

Tags: css, react-native

I have a problem with `react-native` elements. I have one `<Parent>` component that is a `View` and I have one `<Child>` component as a child that is also a `View`. I would like that `<Child>` will always be 100% width and height of `<Parent>`. I know I can pass `width: '100%'` and `height: '100%'` but is it a good way of styling it? What is the best practice to setup parent and child and parent will define width and height and child will always be depending on the parent component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for this , you can use `flex` for style like this :

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";

const Flex = () => {
  return (
    <View style={[styles.container, {
      // Try setting `flexDirection` to `"row"`.
      flexDirection: "column"
    }]}>
      <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "red" }} />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
   
  },
});

export default Flex;
```

for more info see [this](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flexbox)

Comment: This works but only for width when flex-direction is set to row and only for height when flex-direction is set to column. So either I have 100% width or 100% height but I would like to have both

Comment: Okay I think I found that out, next children also had to have flex:1, thank you